# AirDrop Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` or `UIDocumentInteractionController` for Airdrop for sharing the files between devices for my document sharing application.

the same code which was working in iOS7 but now in iOS8 when I'm trying to connecting to other device it keeps on showing waiting but there is no request is sent to the other device.

Is there any thing changed in iOS8? I have checked with safari and other apps they are working fine for the same devices.

What should I need to do? To make them work.

Comment: I think you should ask for permission in order to access the Bluetooth component in the user's device. I had a similar problem using iBeacons not working in iOS8 because of this. Just implemented a few lines of code and worked. Google it for the code i don't have it with me now sorry.

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd Im unable to find anything related what you said... if you have the code can you paste it here. It will be helpful who ever is facing the issue.

Comment: sounds worthy of a bug report to apple. If you do file one, it'd be great to report back here with the radar number so that if any Apple engineers come over this question, they can go looking for it

Comment: @ccjensen the problem is I have been using 7 SDk to build the app and running in iOS 8 so the airdrop was not working. Once I build the app with 8 SDK everything got worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that airdrop was not working due to my application got build with iOS 7 SDK but, when I use 8 SDK the airdrop got worked in iOS 8 and iOS 7 devices.
In order to support airdrop in iOS you need to build you're app with 8 SDK

Comment: this sounds like a bug you should file a radar for, as this would imply that all apps that don't submit a new version built with the iOS 8 SDK will have AirDrop broken